# broacast receiver incoming sms the registration?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

> I have a problem  with a `broadcastreceiver` for incoming SMS.

When i get a incoming sms with SMS_DELIVER_ACTION, the SMS is not in my sms inbox list nor in the others sms app when my app is the default sms app.

I thought the registration was automatic or i have to use uri. It's hard with no tips in doc.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Thank you in advance.

Here's the code :

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private Bundle bundle;
private SmsMessage currentSMS;
private String message;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Gérer le cas où l'appli n'est pas celle par défaut SMS_RECEIVE...
    if((intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_DELIVER_ACTION)) | (intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION))) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming SMS catched!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdu_Objects = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            if (pdu_Objects != null) {

                for (Object aObject : pdu_Objects) {

                    currentSMS = getIncomingMessage(aObject, bundle);

                    String senderNo = currentSMS.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    message = currentSMS.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: " + senderNo + " :\n message: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
               // this.abortBroadcast();
                // End of loop
            }
        }
    }
}

private SmsMessage getIncomingMessage(Object aObject, Bundle bundle) {
    SmsMessage currentSMS;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        String format = bundle.getString("format");
        currentSMS = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aObject, format);
    } else {
        currentSMS = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aObject);
    }

    return currentSMS;
}
```

}

Comment: Just don't forget to ask the permission needed dynamically to the user and it 'll be OK.